# Replace value with row below if fields match, after sorting

Tags: sql, replace, match, partition

I want to match records belonging to the same customer together, if the sex, date of birth (dob) and postcode are the same.

One way to achieve this would be to sort the records and then say "create newid as id, replace newid with the id in the row below, if the postcode is the same as the postcode below, the sex is the same and the date of birth is the same".

What is the most appropriate SQL command for this - I'm not sure how to ask SQL to check "the row below" and replace if a field is the same?

In the example below, newid is what the end result should look like. Those with the same sex, dob and postcode get the same id.

Many thanks

```
 CREATE TABLE mytable(
   id INTEGER(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
 , customerid INTEGER(1)
 , sex INTEGER(1)
 , dob DATE 
 , postcode VARCHAR(7)
 , newid INTEGER(1)
 );
 INSERT INTO mytable(id,customerid,sex,dob,postcode,newid) VALUES (1,1,1,'19320413','AB1 2CD',1);
 INSERT INTO mytable(id,customerid,sex,dob,postcode,newid) VALUES (2,2,1,'19320413','EF3 4GH',2);
 INSERT INTO mytable(id,customerid,sex,dob,postcode,newid) VALUES (3,3,1,'19320413','AB1 2CD',1);
 INSERT INTO mytable(id,customerid,sex,dob,postcode,newid) VALUES (4,4,1,'19320413','AB1 2CD',1);
 INSERT INTO mytable(id,customerid,sex,dob,postcode,newid) VALUES (10,6,2,'19420930','IJ5 6KL',3);
 INSERT INTO mytable(id,customerid,sex,dob,postcode,newid) VALUES (11,7,2,'19420930','IJ5 6KL',3);
 INSERT INTO mytable(id,customerid,sex,dob,postcode,newid) VALUES (12,8,2,'19430930','IJ5 6KL',4);
```

Comment: What database are you using?  What `id` are you talking about?  The field `id` is a primary key, so it cannot be duplicated on different rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on oracle, then analytic functions is what you need (e.g. *dense_rank())*